# How to display any included template according to Symfony user role in twig template

Tags: symfony, twig, roles

I have the following template code.

```
<div class="row">
   {% include 'ProductBundle:Partials:productInfo.html.twig' %}

   {% include 'OrderBundle:Partials:orderInfo.html.twig' %}

   {% include 'DeliveryBundle:Partials:deliveryInfo.html.twig' %}

   {% include 'BillBundle:Partials:billInfo.html.twig' %}
</div>
```

I want to show the first include part for `ROLE_USER`. He can not access the other three includes.
The other users having `ROLE_ADMIN` can access all four include parts.

Is there any way to do it with twig ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
   {% include 'ProductBundle:Partials:productInfo.html.twig' %}

   {% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') -%}
       {% include 'OrderBundle:Partials:orderInfo.html.twig' %}   
       {% include 'DeliveryBundle:Partials:deliveryInfo.html.twig' %}   
       {% include 'BillBundle:Partials:billInfo.html.twig' %}
   {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: @NHG That's not a typo, that's the whitespace control modifier. See also http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#whitespace-control